# Simplify $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x}}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does this simplification work?

$\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x}}{x} =\sqrt{1 + 1/x} $

Comment: $x= \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: Hmm. What if $x=-2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+x}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{x}{x^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$

Note: this is valid for $x>0$, as then $x=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$.

For $x<-1$, the LHS is defined, but negative, while the RHS is positive, so they do not agree.  For $-1<x<0$, the LHS is undefined as you're taking the square root of a negative number.  For $x=-1$, the two sides agree since they're both zero.  For $x=0$, neither side is defined since you're dividing by zero.

Comment: To be precise, this is only correct if $x$ is positive.  For negative values of $x$, it is not true that $x=\sqrt{x^2}$; rather, we should have $x = sgn (x) \sqrt{x^2}$, where $sgn(x)$ is the "sign" or "signum" function, giving 1 or -1 depending on whether $x$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Quite right, I was in the middle of my note when you posted this.